# How to detach a thread(in a pool) in JNI on termination

Tags: c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have a thread pool executing java methods from JNI side. Instead to attach/detach the thread for every method execution i attach the thread once and on thread termination it is executed detaching.
For making it i used TLS because the TLS destructor is executed when thread is terminated.

On unit test it TLS works correctly , all it seams to work correctly but when the process is terminated TLS destructors are not executed.

TLS destructor is associated by pthread_exit executed not on main thread so i tried to add also         atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); }); for forcing to execute trigger method.

However the destructor are not executed. 
I tried to search on google if there were some tracks to follow. 
I found just one. On 2014 a Oracle engineer tried to do a thing similar to mime and he told it works in 32-bit archs and android but not in arch-64bit. For his opinion there is a bug in arch-64bit in which Thread::~Thread inside set to null TLS so destructor is not executed. It seams in the discussion this bug was fixed. 
My JDK version is 1.8.0_131 so i expected that bug was solved
I dont know it this story is true or not, anyway the problem exists.

did anyone find a trick or a solution about this problem? Is there a bug in my code? it is there a way for deleting JNIENV manually (delete env)?(i this case i could create a map with all jnienv used)

```
 JavaVM *JVM;
#ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_10
    jint jvmVersion=JNI_VERSION_1_10;
#elif defined   JNI_VERSION_1_9
      jint jvmVersion=JNI_VERSION_1_9;
#elif defined   JNI_VERSION_1_8
     jint jvmVersion=JNI_VERSION_1_8;
#elif defined   JNI_VERSION_1_7
     jint jvmVersion=JNI_VERSION_1_7;
#elif defined   JNI_VERSION_1_6
    jint jvmVersion=JNI_VERSION_1_6;
#endif


    pthread_key_t CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV;
    static void detach_current_thread(void *env) {
        assert(1!=0);

        std::cout<< "deta\n";
        if (pthread_getspecific (CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV)!=NULL) {
            std::cout<< "deta2\n";
            JVM->DetachCurrentThread();
        }
    }


     JNIEnv *getEnv() {

        JNIEnv *env = (JNIEnv *) pthread_getspecific(CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV);
        std::cout << "1" << JVM << "\n";
        if (env == NULL) {
            int getEnvStat = JVM->GetEnv((void **) &env, jvmVersion);
            std::cout << "2\n";
            if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
                std::cout << "2a\n";
                if (JVM->AttachCurrentThread((void **) &env, NULL) !=
                    JNI_OK) {// expensive operation : do not detach for every invocation

                    jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/lang/Error");
                    if (jc) env->ThrowNew(jc, "unable to attach JNIEnv");

                    return NULL;
                } else {
                    std::cout << "3"  "\n";
                    pthread_setspecific(CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV, env);
                  //  atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });
                    std::cout << "4" "\n";
                }
            } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {

                jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/lang/Error");
                if (jc) env->ThrowNew(jc, "unable to create JNIEnv:version not supported");

                return NULL;

            }else {
                std::cout << "3a\n";
                pthread_setspecific(CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV, env);
               // atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });
                std::cout << "4b\n";
            }
        }
        return env;

    }
}



jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {

    JVM = vm;
    pthread_key_create(CURRENT_ATTACHED_ENV, detach_current_thread);
    atexit([] { ::pthread_exit(0); });
    return jvmVersion;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'TLS' and 'TLS destructor'?

Comment: Thread Local Storage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage. When thread terminating , the function associated to key is executed

Comment: Thank you. It also means Transport Layer Security (RFC 2246) and no doubt other things as well. Using ambiguous or unknown TLAs is not helpful.

Comment: I removed atexit and it is necessary to not use argument in destructor. I dont know the reason why the argoment is not the value and why not atexit